# Need help with the following problem

Tags: graph-theory

In a math class with 24 students the individuals are polled and asked how
many members of the class they are friends with. The result of the poll is as
follows: Three 3 said they are friends with 4 persons in the class; four said they
are friends with 5 persons in the class; six said they are friends with 7 persons
in the class; seven said they are friends with 9 persons in the class; and foursaid
they are friends with 11 persons in the class Explain why some student most
have miscounted their number of friends.

Approach: This seems to be a graph theory problem, so in a graph, any node is a person, and an edge, the relationship between two persons.

All I have is that the upper bound for the # edges of a graph of 24 nodes is ${24 \choose 2} = 276$. I tried to visualize the outflow of edges in every group and found that in the group of 3 people, the outflow is 12 edges, in the group of 4, the outflow is 20, in the group of 6, the outflow is 42, in the group of 7, the outflow is 63, and in the group of 4, the outflow is 44.

Do you have in mind some theorem to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: think about parity of the sum of degrees of the nodes.

Comment: yeah, I was almost certain that there is an "even" thing going on in this problem.

Comment: the sum of the degrees of the nodes is 2(#edges) and 181 is not an even number

Comment: @TheMathNoob Right. It is not necessary to calculate this 181 from problem's conditions, it suffices only to count its parity.

Comment: Why isn't it necessary.181 is the sum of the degrees of all nodes in that graph right?

Comment: @TheMathNoob To obtain a contradiction it suffices only to know that the sum of the degrees is odd, which I did when I read the problem condition.

Comment: At a party there are 25 people. As it happens, among any subset of four
people there is at least one person who knows the other three. Prove that there
is a person at the party who knows all the other people. what about this problem?

Comment: @TheMathNoob I’ll assume that the knowledge is symmetric. Pick any two persons $a$ and $b$ who don’t know each other (if there are no such two then there is nothing to prove). Then for any persons $c$ and $d$ distinct from $a$ and $b$ in the quadruple $\{a,b,c,d\}$ somebody knows all persons. This somebody cannot be $a$ or $b$, so $c$ and $d$ know each other. Thus any two persons distinct from $a$ and $b$ know each other and somebody of them also knows $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming friendship is symmetric, so can be captured by a simple graph, you can use the [handshake lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma).

Comment: friendship is not reflexive. How can you be a friend of yourself?

Comment: Haha, sorry, corrected. Although, philosophically, perhaps that is where friendship should start...

Comment: true, I hate myself.